# Add missing datas through two dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I encountered a small issue about adding datas through two python dictionaries.

Here is my code :

```
dicta = {'name' : 'character', 'age': 30 }
dictb = {'name' : 'Jon'}
```

I would like to add the key and value 'age':30 into dictb. 
So i do :

```
for i in dicta:
    for j in dictb:
        if(i not in dictb):
            dictb.update(i)
```

Then nothing is added and i encounter this issue :

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Is this occuring because there isn't empty space in my dictb ?

How could i solve this issue ?

Thank you for your replies !

Best regards, Karro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a nested loop, as you are currently using. Just iterate over `dicta`'s keys and check if the key exists in `dictb` or not:

```
for k in dicta:
    if k not in dictb:
        dictb[k] = dicta[k]
```

The problem with your existing code is that `i` is a key, not a dictionary. So calling `dict.update(int)` fails. You'd want something along the lines of (for your existing code):

```
dictb.update({ i : dicta[i] })
```

While still getting rid of the inner loop.

Comment: OK thanks, it worked ! :) I got it. Will accept your answer soon ! :)

Answer (score 0):

This will be work fine!.

```
dicta = {'name' : 'character', 'age': 30 }
dictb = {'name' : 'Jon'}
for key, value in dicta.items(): # items() works at python3 use iteritems in 2
    if key not in dictb:
        dictb[key] = value
```

---

better

```
for key in dicta:
    if key not in dictb:
        dictb[key] = dicta[key]
```

Comment: Keeping in mind that `.items`/`.iteritems` is wasteful because you create a copy of the entire dictionary as tuples to iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

use setdefault:dictb.setdefault('age',30)